# What happened to n >35 here?

Tags: plotting

```
f[n_, r_] := (1 - r^2)^((n - 4)/2)/(Beta[1/2, (n - 2)/2])
```

So

```
Grid[  Partition[   Table[    Plot[{f[n, r], PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], r]}, {r, -1, 1},     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 0.55}},     PlotLabel -> "n=" <> ToString[n],     Frame -> True     ], {n, 20, 50, 2}], 4   ], Frame -> All  ]
```

Works fine (step of 2), but

```
Grid[  Partition[   Table[    Plot[{f[n, r], PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], r]}, {r, -1, 1},     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 0.55}},     PlotLabel -> "n=" <> ToString[n],     Frame -> True     ], {n, 20, 50, 5}], 4   ], Frame -> All  ]
```

with step of 5, did not work for no reason...

It went 20,25,30,35 and just STOPPED????

[image]

Comment: change `Partition[..., 4]` to `Partition[..., 4,4,1, {}]`?

Comment: @kglr I see the `cause`, but it would be nice to have a `warning` from MMA. Thanks.

Comment: Chen, `Partition` has quite a few argument patterns. This behavior is clearly documented though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list = Table[n, {n, 20, 50, 5}]
```

> {20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50}

Incomplete sublists at the end are dropped:

```
Partition[list, 4]
```

> {{20, 25, 30, 35}}

Use padding `{}` as the fifth argument of `Partition` to get a ragged list as the result:

```
Partition[list, 4, 4, 1, {}]
```

> {{20, 25, 30, 35}, {40, 45, 50}}